# Push navigation shows 2 view controllers at once in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently experiencing a weird problem when using push navigation. I have 4 view controllers

A -> B -> C -> D

When I push from A to B, I have no problem but when I goes from B to C, my app shows A first then A disappears then C shows up. The order is B -> A -> C instead of just B -> C. It also happens when I push from C to D as well. A still shows up during animation then disappears. C -> A -> D. Have anyone face this problem before?

The method I use is

```
let termVc = TermVC()

 navigationController?.pushViewController(termVc, animated: true)
```

Comment: post code and where you exactly push the VCS

Comment: Do you create segue between them if so , do you hook it to the button that navigates or to the VC , also the push code you attached is inside the button that navigates ???

Comment: I don't create segue between them. I navigate between my view controllers inside did select item at index path method

Comment: The problem is in some code you haven't posted. Perhaps try creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).